# javascript regex replace function removes other content

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a content (string) that in some part contains full urls to youtube and in others just the video ID.
I need to replace the full length youtube urls with the video id only.
var "content" is for example.

```js
var content = '{GENERICO:type="youtube",id="DluFA_AUjV8"}{GENERICO:type="youtube",id="https://youtu.be/DluFA_AUjV8"}';

var myRegex = /{GENERICO:type="youtube",id=".*?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:embed\/|watch\?v\=)?([^\&\?\/\"]+).*?["&\?]}/gi;

content = content.replace(myRegex, '{GENERICO:type="youtube",id="$1"}' );

console.log(content);
```

the result I want to achieve (in the example) is:

```
{GENERICO:type="youtube",id="DluFA_AUjV8"}{GENERICO:type="youtube",id="DluFA_AUjV8"}
```

what I actually get is this following:

```
the result I want to achieve (in the example) is:

{GENERICO:type="youtube",id="DluFA_AUjV8"}
```

for some reason, it removes one of the strings in the content.
I can't figure out if it's a javascript issue or a regex issue or what i'm doing wrong.

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnjoko0h/15/embedded)

Comment: [`({GENERICO:type="youtube",id=")[^"]*(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:embed\/|watch\?v=)?([^&?\/"]+)("[^}]*})`](https://regex101.com/r/nXxQ8w/1)

Comment: how about just `content.replace("https://youtu.be/", "")`

Comment: ctwheels , you answered it.
it was a greedy regex.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `content.replace(new RegExp('https://youtu.be/','g'), '')` for a global replace.

```js
var content = '{GENERICO:type="youtube",id="DluFA_AUjV8"}{GENERICO:type="youtube",id="https://youtu.be/DluFA_AUjV8"}';

console.log(content.replace(new RegExp('https://youtu.be/','g'), ''))
```